# Range of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the multivariable function

> $$\log(y^2+4x^2-4)$$

and I have found the maximal domain to be

> $$x^2+{y^2\over4}>1$$

However I have no idea how to find the range of this function, any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take $y=0.$ Then you can study the range of the function of one variable. Once you got it you will know the range of the multivariable function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** We have
$$
\ln : (0,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$ and
$$
\ln : (1,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+-\left\{0\right\}.
$$

Comment: So if I were to let y = 0,
$$z=log(4x^2-4)$$
Which therefore the range = (1,inf)

Is this correct?

Comment: @user145608 Looking at my second proposition above, you may see that the answer to your question is $\mathbb{R}^+-\left\{0\right\}$, since the argument of your function, that is $x^2+{y^2\over4}$, is greater than $1$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have already found out that the domain $D$ of $f$ is the open exterior  of the ellipse $x^2+{y^2\over4}=1$. The set $D$ contains all points of the form $(x,0)$ with $x>1$, and on these points $f$ assumes the values
$$\phi(x):=\log(4x^2-4)=\log 4+\log(x+1)+\log(x-1)\ .$$
From
$$\lim_{x\to1+}\phi(x)=-\infty,\qquad\lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)=\infty$$
it then follows that $f$ assumes arbitrary real values; whence the range of $f$ is ${\mathbb R}$.